# Dynamically show the count in Angular8

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm working on counting an item-list. The count should reflect dynamically on HTML file when adding or removing items from the item-list.

However, my count is static and need to refresh the page to see the change.

Do you have any advice making it dynamic?

This is my HTML:

```
            <span class="counting-badge" ng-if="SomeCondition">
              {{controller.countRequiredItems()}}
            </span>
```

Here is the function I have in controller:

```
    public countRequiredItems(): number {
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.itemList.length; i++) {
        let item = this.itemList[i];
        if (item.isRequired) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      return count;
    }
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Is this Angular 2+ or AngularJS? look's like AngularJS

Comment: it's angularJS, not angular. I recommend to use angular (please look at www.angular.io)